# python django json.dumps() and javascript cookies

Tags: javascript, python, django

6.5 and django 2.1.a1.  I am having trouble with what I thought might be a simple cookie build.  I create a `dict` for the cookie payload.  I end up with two string keys, each with a string value.

An example is:

```
>>> cookie_payload = dict()
>>> cookie_payload["whereAmI"] = "index"
>>> cookie_payload["account_number"] = "123456789"
>>> json.dumps(cookie_payload, ensure_ascii=True)
'{"whereAmI": "index", "account_number": "123456789"}'
```

The result of the `set_cookie` below however is:

```
'{"whereAmI": "index"\054 "account_number": "123456789"}'
```

when it reaches my javascript. `JSON.parse()` barfs on the "054".  The comma is obviously being escaped but it is not being url encoded.  How do I force that comma to stay a "," or should I decode the string differently in javascript?

```
    @verified_email_required
    def index(request):
        cookie_payload = dict()

        try:
            cookie_payload["whereAmI"] = "index"

            my_profile = Profile.objects.get(user=request.user)
            profile_in_groups = Group.objects.all().filter(
                grouplist__profile__account_number=my_profile.account_number) \
                .order_by('name')

            cookie_payload["account_number"] = my_profile.account_number.__str__()


            my_render = render(request, 'App/index.html', {
                'profile': my_profile
            })
            my_render.set_cookie("Session",
                                 value=json.dumps(cookie_payload, 
                                                 ensure_ascii=True))
        except ObjectDoesNotExist:
            my_render = redirect('profile-create')
            my_render.set_cookie("Session",
                                 value=json.dumps(cookie_payload, 
                                                 ensure_ascii=True))

        return my_render
```